# Converting a tuple to a string in erlang language

Tags: erlang

```
Tuple={<<"jid">>,Member},

Tuple_in_string=lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Tuple])),
```

it gives output as:

```
"{<<\"jid\">>,\"sdfs\"}"
```

But i want this output without these slashes like

```
"{<<"jid">>,Member}"
```

Any pointers?

I have tried all the answers but at the end with io:format("\"~s\"~n", [Tuple_in_string]). what am geeting is "{<<"jid">>,Member}" but it is not a string.it is a atom.I need string on which i can apply concat operation.Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can print it like this:

```
io:format("\"~s\"~n", [Tuple_in_string]).
```

It prints:

```
"{<<"jid">>,"sdfs"}"
```

Comment: :io:format("\"~s\"~n", [Tuple_in_string]).=>"{<<"jid">>,"sdfs"}".When i tried to concat it with a string it produced error.Finally i collected the result("{<<"jid">>,"sdfs"}") in variable V. and is_atom(V) is true.But i need a string

Answer (score 0):

The \ are here to denote that the following " is part of the string and not a string delimiter. they do not exist in the string itself. They appear because you use the pretty print format ~p. If you use the string format ~s they wont appear in the display.

```
1> io:format("~p~n",["a \"string\""]).               
"a \"string\""
ok
2> io:format("~s~n",["a \"string\""]).
a "string"
ok
3> length("a \"string\""). % is 10 and not 12                     
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to flatten the list here:

```
Tuple_in_string=lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [Tuple])),
```

Erlang has the concept of `iodata()`, which means that printable things can be in nested lists and most functions can handle them, so you should leave only:

```
Tuple_in_string = io_lib:format("~p", [Tuple]),
```

Secondly, when you use `~p`, you tell Erlang to print the term in such way, that it can be copied and pasted into console. That is why all double quotes are escaped `\"`. Use `~s`, which means "treat as string".

```
1> 38> Tuple = {<<"jid">>,"asdf"}.
{<<"jid">>,"asdf"}
2> IODATA = io_lib:format("~p", [Tuple]).
[[123,[[60,60,"\"jid\"",62,62],44,"\"asdf\""],125]]
3> io:format("~s~n", [IODATA]).
{<<"jid">>,"asdf"}
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L =  Packet_in_tuple_form={xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"rkX6Q-8">>},{<<"to">>,<<"multicast.devlab">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,"Hello"}]},{xmlel,<<"addresses">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/address">>}],[{xmlel,<<"address">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},"{<<\"jid\">>,\"sds\"}",{<<"desc">>,"Description"}],[]}]}]}.
```

Gives me:

```
{xmlel,<<"message">>,
   [{<<"id">>,<<"rkX6Q-8">>},{<<"to">>,<<"multicast.devlab">>}],
   [{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,"Hello"}]},
    {xmlel,<<"addresses">>,
           [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/address">>}],
           [{xmlel,<<"address">>,
                   [{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},
                    "{<<\"jid\">>,\"sds\"}",
                    {<<"desc">>,"Description"}],
                   []}]}]}
```

The \ in the address field are escape characters.
You can verify the same by checking the length of string.